# Pushforward measure of composition

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I have a really embarrassing question.I'm probably just computing these wrong, but:

Let $T: X \rightarrow Y$ and $S: Y \rightarrow Z$ be measurable maps between measure spaces. Is it true that the pushforward measure of $\mu$ on $X$ (I'm not writing the $\sigma$-aglebras attached to these spaces) by $ST$, denoted by $(ST)_*\mu$ is the same as $S_*T_*\mu$? We have:

$(ST)_*\mu (-) = \mu ((ST)^{-1} -) = \mu (T^{-1}S^{-1} -)$.

But, 
$S_*T_*\mu (-) := S_*\mu (T^{-1} -) = \mu(S^{-1}T^{-1}-)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true that $(ST)_*\mu=S_*T_*\mu$; your computation of $S_*T_*\mu(-)$ is wrong.  Notice that $S_*T_*\mu$ means $(S_*(T_*\mu))$: that is, the pushforward of $T_*\mu$ along $S$.  So $$S_*T_*\mu(-)=(S_*(T_*\mu))(-)=T_*\mu(S^{-1}-)=\mu(T^{-1}S^{-1}-).$$

Comment: Thanks! I should know better... I'll accept in three minutes when I'm able to.